# Click Checkbox by Value Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, pageobjects

I have google around a bit trying to finds some way you can click check boxes by entering a value, similar what you can use to select values in Drop Down  List.
But havent found a way yet.

I have two check boxes with Yes and No

```
div class="radio">
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="LongTermContract" value="Yes" autocomplete="off" checked="">Yes
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="LongTermContract" value="No" autocomplete="off">No                                </label>                          
</div>
```

I'm also using PageObjects,

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "LongTermContract")]
public IWebElement radioBtnLongTermContract { get; set; }
```

This is the Method I have.

```
    public static void SelectOptions(this IWebElement element, string value)
    {
        PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='" + value + "']")).Click();

    }
```

Now if im trying this

```
public void SelectValue(){
  Reporting("NO"); 
    }
```

I get an error that it does not find the element

> Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='NO']"}

Any ideas tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code snippet is in java. You need to pass value either **Yes** or **No** it will select respective radio button as the same value used for `<input>` tag's attribute `value`

```
public static void SelectOptions(String value)
{
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='"+value+"']")).click();
 }
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, getting this error though.

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='NO']"}

Comment: I believe xpath is case sensitive, so "NO" will not match, you need to use "No"